# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'range' and 'float' エラーが出る。

Tags: python, データの可視化

本を参考に、確率密度関数のコードを書き、

```
def normal_dist_pdf(x, mu, sigma):   

　　"""
　　正規分布
　　: param x: x
　　: param mu: 平均
　　: param sigma: 標準偏差
　　: return: 正規分布
　　"""
　　# expの部分
　　exp = np.exp(-1 * ((x-mu)**2/(2*sigma**2)))

　　# 残りの部分 xexpの部分
　　return (1/(np.sqrt(2* math.pi*sigma**2))) * exp
```

これを[仙台　日平均気温の月平均値（℃）](http://www.data.jma.go.jp/obd/stats/etrn/view/monthly_s3.php?prec_no=34&block_no=47590&year=&month=&day=&elm=monthly&view=a1)の11月で使ってみようと思いました。

```
pd.DataFrame(Miyagi_temp['11月'].describe())

11月
count   94.000000
mean    8.896809
std 1.165125
min 6.500000
25% 8.100000
50% 8.800000
75% 9.700000
max 11.800000
```

次に、実際にヒストグラムを描いて関数で線を引くために、下記のコードを試しました。

```
# 実際のデータのヒストグラム
ax = Miyagi_temp['11月'].plot(kind = 'hist', bins=94)

# 6.5 から 11.8 までを対象（今回のデータの範囲）
x = range(6, 12)

# 今回作った関数でラインを引く
y = [normal_dist_pdf(x, mu, sigma) for i in x]

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(x, y, color = 'r', linewidth = 5.0)
```

しかし、エラーが発生。

```
<ipython-input-47-a5a5417f49ac> in normal_dist_pdf(x, mu, sigma)
     10     """
     11     # expの部分
---> 12     exp = np.exp(-1 * ((x-mu)**2/(2*sigma**2)))
     13 
     14     # 残りの部分 xexpの部分

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'range' and 'float'
```

range()関数とfloat型の間に問題がありそうなんですが、どうも原因がつかめません。

本の例ではうまくできていたのですが。
何かヒントあればありがたいです。

Comment: `x` は `numpy.ndarray` の方が良いでしょう。`x = np.arange(6, 12)`

Comment: ありがとうございます。
解決しました。ndarrayや配列もう少し調べてみることにします。